# waiting once after sending kill signal to multiple processes?

Tags: c, process, kill, waitpid

So I'm working on a project for one of my programming classes, and part of this assignment is about being able to launch process in the background, and being able to kill them when the user types "endb".

In order to kill the background processes, I have an array (PIDpool) which holds the PIDs of all the processes, and whenever the user input "endb", I go through this array of PIDs and kill them one by one.

Though, in order for this to work, I had to add a single wait after I sent a kill signal to each process. If I didn't, there would be a single defunct process left, and if I put a wait for each kill signal (by putting the wait within the killing loop), the program would hang.

While I'm happy to know my program seems to be working, I'm wondering why that wait is necessary, cuz it would seem to me that I would need either to wait for each process after killing them or wait for none at all...

Thanks in advance ^^

```
static void backgroundExecution(char** cmd_tokens){
    if(!strcmp(cmd_tokens[0], "endb")){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < arraySize(PIDpool); i++){
            intptr_t PID = (intptr_t) arrayGet(PIDpool, i);
            kill(PID, SIGKILL);
        }
        wait(NULL);   // <------------ THIS WAIT HERE
        arrayEmpty(PIDpool);
    }else{
        pid_t PID = fork();
        if(PID == 0){
            execvp(cmd_tokens[0], cmd_tokens);
        }else{
            arrayPushBack(PIDpool, (void*) (unsigned long) PID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, why are you casting `pid_t` to `intptr_t`? The problem is clearly not in waiting because waiting on a process guaranteed to be a zombie will just reap it and return immediately, unless `kill` doesn't send a signal and returns an error, which you don't check.

Comment: I'm casting it into intptr_t because I'm using a general purpose array header I imported from another project which stores its elements as void*. And if I cast a void* into a pid_t I get a warning because I am casting to a smaller integer type

Answer (score 0):

Look deeper into [`wait()` and `waitpid()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html). Wait simply waits for any child process to terminate, thus it works in your case. 
You actually don't check whether each process has indeed stopped, nor whether the [`kill`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) function returned an error. 
As pointed out in the comments, your cast to `intptr_t` is incorrect, not sure what the type of `PIDpool` is but it should look like `pid_t PIDpool[POOL_SIZE];`

Comment: Ok, so the reason I'm casting into intptr is because the array I am using is a general purpose array header I had from another project which stores everything as void* and if I convert void* to pid_t, I get an error for casting a pointer into a smaller int type.

Comment: As for the waiting part, I know it waits for any process to terminate, but here, say there are 2 background processes, I would assume I either have to wait twice (since two processes have been stopped) or not wait at all (because maybe the kill signal frees ressources of the child process) but neither of those work.